Need help with a question about cardinality and perhaps model theory
Let $I$ be the unit interval. Call a collection $\Sigma$ of subsets of $I$ "valid" if it satisfies the following three conditions:

$I \in \Sigma$.
$\Sigma$ has the same cardinality as $I$.
Each element $\sigma \in \Sigma$ has the same cardinality as $I$.

For a valid set $\Sigma$, say that $\Sigma$ is "founded" by a set $A$ and relation $\phi$ if:

$A$ is countable.
$\forall x,y \in I$, we have that $x=y$ if and only if $\phi(a,x)$ holds precisely when $\phi(a,y)$ holds.
For each $\sigma \in \Sigma$, there is a sequence of finite subsets $\sigma_n \subseteq A$, such that $\forall x \in I$, $x \in \sigma$ iff $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$ there is an  $a_k \in \sigma_k$ such that $\phi(a_k, x)$.

Let $\Sigma$ be a valid set. A "valid cut" $\Sigma'$ of $\Sigma$ is a valid set such that each element of $\Sigma$ is a superset of an element of $\Sigma'$.
My question is whether there is always some valid cut of $\Sigma$ that is founded by some $A$ and $\phi$?.
A tangible example can be constructed when $\Sigma$ is the set of all non-empty open intervals in $I$. Here we can set $A$ to be the set of finite binary strings and $\phi(a,x)$ to be the "prefix" relation, i.e: $\phi(a,x)$ precisely when $a$ is a prefix of the binary expansion of $x$ (ignoring the leading '$0.$'), outlawing binary expansions ending in all $1$'s. Does the set of finite binary strings still work in all cases, if we adjust the definition of $\phi$ accordingly?
I like to visualise this problem as "compressing" the information in $(I, \Sigma)$ into a countable set $A$, and using $\phi$ to "decode" it.
I would like some help with finding a solution, my approach would be to use model theory, since Lowenheim-Skolem can be used to ensure $A$ is countable. I have also briefly met filters and ultrafilters before, and this problem reminds me of them a little, although I don't know any results about filters yet.

I'm not sure I've deciphered your question correctly but it seems to be an opaque and convoluted way of asking: Given a family $\Sigma$ of subsets of $I$ with $|\Sigma|=|I|$, does there exist a countable collection $A$ of sets such that every element of $\Sigma$ can be represented as a countable intersection of [finite unions of] elements of $A$? Or something like that? How would you do that if $\Sigma={I\setminus{x}:x\in I}$, i.e., the complements of singleton sets?

@user14111 Oh sorry I accidentally forgot part of the question. You are allowed to replace $\Sigma$ with another set $\Sigma'$ satisfying the same properties, provided that each element of $\Sigma$ is a superset of some element in $\Sigma'$. I've updated my question to reflect this.

I don’t think your example where $\Sigma$ consists of all nonempty open intervals works. If it’s non-degenerate closed intervals, this is fine, but for open interval, say for $(0, 1)$, because it contains elements that have arbitrarily many $0$ at the front, $\sigma_n$ has to always contain an all-zero string, so $0$ would be in the intersection, but $0 \notin (0, 1)$. (Of course, all non-degenerate closed intervals form a valid cut of all nonempty open intervals, so this is not a counterexample, just that your example does not work as is.)

Let me rephrase this question in topological terms: let $X$ be a set of cardinality continuum, $\Sigma$ be a collection of continuum many subsets of $X$, each one of cardinality continuum. Does there exist a second-countable topology $\tau$ on $X$, s.t. each $\sigma \in \Sigma$ majorizes a closed set (under $\tau$) of cardinality continuum?

Here's an affirmative (but nonconstructive) answer. It is quite simple and straightforward, although it may look complicated and obscure after I've transcribed it (I hope correctly but who knows) into your notation.
Claim 1. If $\Sigma$ is a valid collection of subsets of $I$, and if the elements of $\Sigma\setminus\{I\}$ are pairwise disjoint sets, then $\Sigma$ is founded by some countable set $A$ and some relation $\phi\subseteq A\times I$.
Claim 2. If $\Sigma$ is a valid collection of subsets of $I$, then $\Sigma$ has a valid cut $\Sigma'$ such that the elements of $\Sigma'\setminus\{I\}$ are pairwise disjoint sets.
Proof of Claim 1. Let $\Sigma\setminus\{I\}=\{\sigma_f:f\in\{0,1\}^\mathbb N\}$, where $\sigma_f\ne\sigma_g$ when $f\ne g$. Fix a bijection $h:I\to\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$. Let $A=\mathbb N\times\{0,1,2\}$. I will define a relation $\phi\subseteq A\times I$.
For $n\in\mathbb N$ and $x\in I$, define
$$\phi((n,2),x)\iff h_n(x)=0.$$
The reason for this is to satisfy the second condition in your definition of "founded".
For $n\in\mathbb N$, $\varepsilon\in\{0,1\}$, and $x\in I$, define
$$\phi((n,\varepsilon),x)\iff x\in\bigcup\{\sigma_f:f(n)=\varepsilon\}.$$
Proof of Claim 2. Well-order the set $\Sigma\times I$ so that each proper initial segment has cardinality less than $|I|$. Recursively choose distinct elements $x_{\sigma,t}$ for $(\sigma,t)\in\Sigma\times I$ so that $x_{\sigma,t}\in\sigma$. Let $\Sigma'=\{I\}\cup\{\sigma':\sigma\in\Sigma\}$ where $\sigma'=\{x_{\sigma,t}:t\in I\}\subseteq\sigma$.

Yay! Can you think of a better name for sets like $\Sigma$ other than "valid"?
